# Battery Level Instant Drop

Tags: battery-life, motorola

Recently, muy phone has had several instances of instant battery level drop; not as in quick drain, but rather, immediate drop. I've been able to document these two occurrences :

[image: INSTANT DROP]

[image: INSTANT DROP]

Between the first and second occurrence, I uninstalled apps that were using data on the background (such as games and whatnot), I monitored the battery usage per application, disabled unused applications, and used motorola's app battery optimization. And while doing all that did in fact improved my overall battery life, that didn't prevent it from "spontaneously" dropping to near 0%.

Also, I  noticed  that in both cases, there was a slight increment in battery level, before dying (It was charging but I had to unplug it to attend a call).

Finally, there was no significant phone or battery heating that I could perceive.

Another sympton, although I'm unsure this is related in any way, is that my phone turned off, as if battery completely depleted, while having battery level at 15:

[image: Phone shutdown]

I've tried wiping my cache partition, and hasn't occurred since; however, I think that this might be purely coincidental.

My phone information:

[image: Motorola]

I have not been able to find this question repeated here on SE.

Any further needed information I can provide, please ask.

Regards.

Comment: Are you sure your case is unique from ALL [these](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22battery+drain%22+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) former similar questions? How do those suggestions fail you, if you have attempted the suggested solutions? Even if you eliminate due to low confifence in the non-accepted, there are plenty of accepted answers to assume successful resolution(s) there to choose from.

Comment: Because many of the questions you suggest speak of battery draining, either by processes hogging resources or other similar situations. While I have had those issues, if you map the battery behavior, you can see a steep curve to low battery levels. Here, you can it's almost instantaneous, from literally a couple seconds. I doubt it's an issue of battery usage per application.

Comment: I think you are trying to find a presumptive solution that fits your mindset. How have you eliminated the possibility of a common solution?

Comment: Between the first and second occurrence, I uninstalled apps that were using data on the background (such as games and whatnot), I monitored the battery usage per application, disabled unused applications, and used motorola's app battery optimization. And while doing all that did in fact improved my overall battery life, that didn't prevent it from "spontaneously" dropping to near 0%. Also, notice that in both cases, there was a slight increment in battery level, before dying (It was charging but I had to unplug it to attend a call). Finally, there was no significant phone or battery heating

Comment: These are all significant factors that could have been (and probably still should be) edited into the post, rather than as expository comments. Thanks for the additional info, though, since it clears the easier solutions from the possibles.

Comment: Noted and edited :)

Comment: Better get the bad battery replaced.